# A question on Riemannian manifolds without conjugate points

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a complete metric $g$ without conjugate points. We will denote by $K$ the Gaussian curvature.

Question: Is there a constant $C >0$ such that $K(p) \leq C$, for every $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Just an idea for a counterexample: take the hyperbolic plane and put infinitely many spherical caps on it with radii tending to 0...

Comment: It seems to me that a counterexample, as described by Ivan, can be constructed by making sure there are only finitely many caps of appropriate size along any geodesic.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev Why don't you write it as an answer, so the question will be closed?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I'm no more sure it works. A geodesic going "straight through" a bubble is not minimizing; the shortest one with the same endpoints "goes across a slope". So it seems, for an appropriate choice of endpoints, the minimizing geodesic will have a Jacobi field vanishing at the endpoints. Right?

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev No, not if the bubble has small diameter.

Answer (score 10):

It boils down to the following statement.

> There a rotationally symmetric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ without conjugate points, with huge positive curvature at $0$ and curvature $\equiv -1$ outside of the unit ball.

If such metrics are constructed, then we can cut pieces from it and glue them together along domains of curvature $\equiv -1$.
This way we construct a Riemannian manifold without conjugate points and no upper curvature bounds. 
(We need to spread the unit balls far apart, so globally the glued space looks like Lobachevsky plane, and yet make sure no geodesic pass thru 3 balls — this is easy to achieve.)

To construct such examples, 
prescribe the curvature depending on the distance to the origin, so that at $0$ it is huge positive, but quickly becomes $-1$ and stay constant. 
The *no conjugate points condition* follows from the Jacobi equation.